# Swift - Return array data in tableView with custom filter

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView within a UIViewController that loads the ranking of users. Having only one ranking list was a little bit too limited, so I have added a custom bar to load different rankings (weekly, monthly and yearly). The reason why I chose to do it this way is because it gave me a lot of control over my layout constraints - segmented control does not.

The current problem is that I don't exactly know how to return the right array based on the selected tab in my menu bar. As of now I use a fourth empty array to copy the data of one of the other three when the tab is selected, but how do I send this data back to my initial view so that I can return the count in my tableView's numberOfRowsInSection?

**ViewController & TableViewController**

```
class Rank: NSObject{
    var name: String
    var points: Int

init(name: String, points: Int) {
      self.name = name
      self.points = points
    }
}

var rankingArrayWeek = [Rank]()
var rankingArrayMonth = [Rank]()
var rankingArrayTotal = [Rank]()
var filteredRanking = [Rank]()

class RankingController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupMenuBar()

    tableView?.delegate = self

    rankingArrayWeek = [
        Rank(name: "Name1", points: 200)
    ]

    rankingArrayMonth = [
        Rank(name: "Name1", points: 300),
        Rank(name: "Name2", points: 200),
    ]

    rankingArrayTotal = [
        Rank(name: "Name1", points: 500),
        Rank(name: "Name2", points: 400),
        Rank(name: "Name3", points: 300),
    ]

    let rankingTableViewController = RankingTableViewController()

    self.addChildViewController(rankingTableViewController)
    rankingTableViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(rankingTableViewController.view)

    rankingTableViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    rankingTableViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    rankingTableViewController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    rankingTableViewController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
}

lazy var menuBar: MenuBar = {
    let menuBar = MenuBar()
    menuBar.rankingController = self
    return menuBar
}()

private func setupMenuBar() {
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: menuBar)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(50)]", views: menuBar)
   }
}

 // MARK: TableViewController
class RankingTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  let cellId = "cellId"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      tableView?.register(RankCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
      tableView?.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
      tableView?.rowHeight = 60
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return filteredRanking.count
  }
}
```

**My custom menubar**

```
class MenuBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    return collectionView
}()

let cellId = "cellId"
let names = ["Week", "Month", "Total"]

var rankingController: RankingController?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    addSubview(collectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)

    let selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(item: 2, section: 0)
    collectionView.selectItem(at: selectedIndexPath as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)

    setupHorizontalBar()
}

var horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

func setupHorizontalBar() {
    let horizontalBarView = UIView()
    horizontalBarView.backgroundColor = Constants.MAIN_THEME_COLOR
    horizontalBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(horizontalBarView)

    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint = horizontalBarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor)
    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true
    horizontalBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    horizontalBarView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).isActive = true
    horizontalBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4).isActive = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let x = CGFloat(indexPath.item) * frame.width / 3
    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.constant = x

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        filteredRanking = rankingArrayWeek
        print(filteredRanking.count)
    } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
        filteredRanking = rankingArrayMonth
        print(filteredRanking.count)
    } else {
        filteredRanking = rankingArrayTotal
        print(filteredRanking.count)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MenuCell

    cell.buttonView.text = "\(names[indexPath.item])"
    cell.buttonView.textColor = Constants.MAIN_THEME_COLOR

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
}
```

**Updated code:**

To preselect the first row, I also added this to my `cellForItemAt indexPath`:

```
if (cell.isSelected == false) {
        didSelect?(kinds[0])
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest that you add a callback on your menu bar that says what kind of rank has been selected. You can also use this "Kind" to drive the display of the menu bar.

```
enum RankKind: String {
    case week = "Week"
    case month = "Month"
    case total = "Total"
}

class MenuBar {

    let kinds = [RankKind.week, .month, .total]

    var didSelect: ((RankKind)->())?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return kinds.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        cell.buttonView.text = kinds[indexPath.item].rawValue)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        didSelect?(kinds[indexPath.item])
    }
}
```

Then the RankingController can set itself up to know when the menu has changed kind.

```
class RankingController {

    func viewDidLoad() {

        menuBar.didSelect = { kind in
            rankingTableViewController.rankingArray = self.rankingArrayFor(kind: kind)
        }

    }

    func rankingArrayFor(kind: RankKind) -> [Rank] {
        switch kind {
        case .week: return rankingArrayWeek
        case .month: return rankingArrayMonth
        case .total:return rankingArrayTotal
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, the RankingTableViewController exposes its model (an array), and reloads its tableview when that model is reset.

```
class RankingTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var rankingArray: [Rank] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is additional to the original question's code existing for brevity, i.e it is not stand alone.

Comment: Very pleased I could help :D

Comment: John, could you help me with one more thing, please? When I launch my application and go to the ranking tab, all the tables are initially empty. The tableview only returns the data when I tap one of the menu bar items. Since the first menu bar item is "week", I want to load that list right away. The others are fine, because they will be handled by the selected state of the menu. Thank you for your support :D